# Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /var/www/xxxxx.com/contact.php on line 35

Tags: php, forms, contacts, implode

I am getting this warning when the form is submitted without entering any of the fields. The error seems to me from line 35 which uses the implode(). Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you so much for looking.
Thank you so much for looking.
Thank you so much for looking.
Thank you so much for looking.

```
<?php 
$your_email ='email@gmail.com';// <<=== update to your email address

session_start();
$errors = '';
$name = '';
$lastname = '';
$phone = '';
$address = '';
$zipcode = '';
$city = '';
$state = '';
$interested_in = array();
$interested_in = '';
$visitor_email = '';
$user_message = '';
$ansday = '';
$hidansday='';
 
$qnday=rand(1,7);

$hidansday=$qnday+1;
if($hidansday==8) {$hidansday=1;}
$whatday=jddayofweek ( cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN, 1,$qnday, 2012) , 1 );

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $interested_in = implode(",", $_POST['interested_in']);
    $visitor_email = $_POST['visitor_email'];
    $user_message = $_POST['message'];
    $hiddenansday= $_POST['hidansday'];
    $ansday = $_POST['ansday'];
    
    $dw1=trim(strtolower($ansday));
    $dw2=strtolower(trim(jddayofweek (cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN, 1,$hiddenansday, 2012) , 1 )));
                                
    
    ///------------Do Validations-------------
        
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['visitor_email']);
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$visitor_email))
    {
        $errors .= "\n E-mail address not valid ";
    }
    
    if ($dw1!==$dw2)
    {
        $errors .= "\n Please enter valid day for the Security Question";
    }
    
    if(empty($name))
    {
        $errors .= "\n First Name is a required field. ";   
    }
    if(empty($address))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Please enter your address. ";    
    }
    if(empty($zipcode))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Please enter your ZIP Code.  ";  
    }
    if(empty($city))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Please enter your City.  ";  
    }
    if(empty($state))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Please enter your State.  "; 
    }
    
    
    if( !preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i", $phone) ) {
    $errors .= "\n Please enter a valid phone number "; 
    }
    
    if(empty($errors))
    {
        //send the email
        $to = $your_email;
        $subject="Web Form";
        $from = $visitor_email;
        $ip = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '';
        
        $body = "A user  $name submitted the contact form:\n".
        
        "First Name: $name\n".
        "Last Name: $lastname \n".
        "Phone: $phone \n".
        "Email: $visitor_email \n".
        "Address: $address \n".
        "Zip Code: $zipcode \n".
        "City: $city \n".
        "State: $state \n".
        "Interested In (Check all that apply): $interested_in \n".
        "Message: \n ".
        "$user_message\n".
        "IP: $ip\n";    
        
        $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
        
        mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers);
        
        header('Location: thankyou.php');
    }
}


?>
```

This is the HTML part.

```
<p>
                        Service Interested In <small>(Check all that apply):</small> <br/>
                        <input name="interested_in[]" type="checkbox" id="interested_in1" value="Internet"/> Internet<br>
                        <input name="interested_in[]" type="checkbox" id="interested_in2" value="Telephone" /> Telephone<br>
                        <input name="interested_in[]" type="checkbox" id="interested_in3" value="Key System" /> Key Systems<br>
                    </p>
```

Comment: Don't just pad out your question with the same text over and over. The requirement for a minumum amout of text is to encourage you to explain your problem fully, and include any debugging information that might be useful. Take the [tour] you were offered when you posted, and see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tick at least one of the checkboxes and submit the form , there will be no error/warning because $_POST['interested_in'] will not be empty.

However, if you do **not** tick any of the checkboxes, then system will prompt warning because now $_POST['interested_in'] is empty but you try to use implode() on it.

Hence, you need to check whether $_POST['interested_in'] has value(s) or not first, say by using `isset`

So, change the line

```
$interested_in = implode(",",$_POST['interested_in']);
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['interested_in'])){
    $interested_in = implode(",",$_POST['interested_in']);
}
```